# Command in Linux crontab to show all output whether success or not

Tags: cron, output, root, ntp

Firstly, I try run this command =
/usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.20

The output is =
adjust time server 192.168.1.20 offset 0.000130 sec

When I try another IP which is not an NTP server =
/usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.30

The output is =
No server suitable for synchronization found

Then, I write some command in the crontab =

1 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.20 >> /home/ntp/twenty

2 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.30 >> /home/ntp/thirty

The output in the file (twenty) is =
adjust time server 192.168.1.20 offset 0.000130 sec

But there is nothing in the file (thirty)

I expect "No server suitable for synchronization found" is written in the file (thirty)

Is there any way to show the output of the ntp whether successfully synchronized or not?

Answer (score 0):

What you want has been answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Because the message you are seeking is stderr, use this:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.30 &>> /home/ntp/thirty
```